# Apply comments votes to parent node (with Rate module)

Tags: 7, rating

My site have a fivestar field in comments, where users gives their vote and the points are applied to the parent node. This is possible using Fivestar module, following this instructions: http://drupalclinic.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/add-fivestar-ratings-in-comments-and.html

Could the same be done with Rate module (https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) and without custom coding?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

And also unlike **Fivestar** module, where the rating field can be made visible in node/comment form and node/comment display, the **Rate** module allows you to add the field only on node/comment display, not on form.

Comment: Maybe using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692101/display-rate-module-in-drupal-7-template or some other "hacky" solution??